# Zero energy for two opposite traveling waves

Tags: optics, waves, string, superposition

Is it possible for two waves travelling the opposite way on a rope of some finite length $L$ (connected to two infinite ropes on the edges) to have a total of zero energy?
For example, if we look at:

$$\psi(0<x<L,t)=Ae^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{L}x-\omega t\right)}+Be^{i\left(-\frac{\pi}{L}x-\omega t\right)}$$
And calculate
$$\rho_{Energy}=\frac{\rho}{2}\left(\left(\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}\right)^{2}+c^{2}\left(\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\right)^{2}\right)$$

the total energy:

$$ E = \int_{0}^{L} \rho_{Energy} dx $$

is zero. I can't seem to make any physical sense out of it. Is my math wrong or is there some physical explanation for this result?

Comment: If you actually took the squares of the complex waves, then it might be zero yes. If you take the real part of $\psi$ and perform the same calculation, it won't be zero.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to work with the real part. But why does it happen?

Comment: I think it's because when you are working in wave mechanics, the physical wavefunction $\psi(x,t)$ should always be a real function. Sometimes authors give complex solutions to the wave equation because you can manipulate them better (the same techniques are utilized in electronics as well). But in the end, you should always consider the real part of your solution as the physical one.